# freemarker test for list and iterate it

Tags: templates, freemarker

I have a data element that can either be a Map or a List of Maps.

Here are two simplified data examples (expressed as JSON for readability)

1) Maps

```
{
    "lom:general": {
        "lom:title": {"lom:string": {
            "language": "fr",
            "content": "Premiers Pas avec un Progiciel de Gestion Intégré"
        }},
        "lom:language": "fr"
    },
    "lom:technical": {"lom:location": "http://hub11.ecolearning.eu/course/progiciel-metiers-pgi/"}
}
```

2) List of Maps

```
{
    "lom:general": {
        "lom:title": {"lom:string": [
            {
                "language": "fr",
                "content": "DIY Education aux médias et à l'information - 3ed"
            },
            {
                "language": "en",
                "content": "DIY Media and Information Literacy - 3ed"
            }
        ]},
        "lom:language": [
            "fr",
            "en"
        ]
    },
    "lom:technical": {"lom:location": "http://hub5.ecolearning.eu/course/diy-do-it-yourself/"}
}
```

I want to check the type of element lom:general.lom:title.lom:string and iterate it if it is a list.

I have tried the following:

```
<title>
    <#assign titles = lom\:general.lom\:title.lom\:string>
    <#if titles?is_enumerable>
        <#list titles as title>
            <string language="${title.language}">${title.content}</string>
        </#list>
    <#else>
        <string language="${titles.language}">${titles.content}</string>
    </#if>
</title>
```

The template works as expected with the first data example. However, the second data example raises a StackOverflowError

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.checkPackageAccess(ReflectUtil.java:188)
at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.checkPackageAccess(ReflectUtil.java:164)
at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl.getGenericDeclaration(TypeVariableImpl.java:164)
at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl.equals(TypeVariableImpl.java:189)
at com.sun.beans.TypeResolver.resolve(TypeResolver.java:190)
at com.sun.beans.TypeResolver.resolve(TypeResolver.java:201)
```

Where the last line is repeated dozens of times

Comment: Give example of data for `element` object, because it may be a problem in this case.

Comment: Also since you have the full (and certainly very long) stack trace, you can see the part in it that's repeated for ever.

Comment: OK, I have edited the question by adding two real data examples and the template fragment I use.  Re. the stack trace, the line  "at com.sun.beans.TypeResolver.resolve(TypeResolver.java:201)" is indeed repeated many times.